# Implementing a toupper function in x86 assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, ascii

I'm playing around with x86 assembly in VS 2012 trying to convert some old code I have to assembly. The problem I'm having is accessing and changing array values (the values are characters) and I'm not sure how to go about it. I've included comments so you can see my thought process

```
    void toUpper(char *string) {
    __asm{

    PUSH EAX
    PUSH EBX
    PUSH ECX
    PUSH EDX
    PUSH ESI
    PUSH EDI

    MOV EBX, string
    MOV ECX, 0 // counter
    FOR_EXPR: // for loop
    CMP EBX, 0 //compare ebx to 0
    JLE END_FOR // if ebx == 0, jump to end_for
    CMP EBX, 97 // compare ebx to 97
    JL ELSE // if  ebx < 97, jump else
    CMP EBX, 122 // compare ebx to 122
    JG ELSE // if ebx > 122, jump else

    // subtract 32 from current array value
    // jump to next element

    JMP END_IF

    ELSE:
    // jump to next element

    END_IF:
    JMP FOR_EXPR

    END_FOR:


    POP EDI
    POP ESI
    POP EDX
    POP ECX
    POP EBX
    POP EAX

       }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the basic problem is that you're loading EBX with the *address* of the string, but then trying to use it as if it contained a byte of data from inside the string.

I'd probably do things a bit differently. I'd probably load the address of the string into ESI  and use it to read the contents of the string indirectly.

```
    mov esi, string
next_char:
    lodsb
    test al, al     ; check for end of string
    jz done      
    cmp al, 'a'     ; ignore unless in range
    bl next_char
    cmp al, 'z'
    bg next_char
    sub al, 'a'-'A' ; convert to upper case         
    mov [esi-1], al ; write back to string
    jmp next_char
```

You can use EBX for that instead of ESI, but ESI is a lot more idiomatic. There are also some tricks you could use to optimize this a little, but until you understand the basics, they'd mostly add confusion. With a modern processor, they probably wouldn't make much difference anyway--this is likely to run as fast as your bandwidth to memory anyway.

Comment: Ah ok thank you for the reply :) Also, how can you de-reference a pointer in assembly?

Comment: The code shows a couple of the most common ways. `lodsb` implicitly loads `al` from the address pointed to by `esi`, then increments `esi`. The `mov [esi-1], al` moves `al` to the address (minus one, in this case) held in `esi`.